# make javascript wait for php

Tags: javascript, php

I made a webpage that gets his data from a string out of a visual basic project and sends it to a mysql. now it has to shutdown the browser (internet explorer) after it has ran his php. now i found a way to close it without the "a script is trying to shut your browser down" promt, but it kills it too quick and the data never reaches the database. and i want it to wait (preferably till the php script is done but if its not possible then for a few seconds)

here is my php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

//variabelen terughalen
$user = $_GET['userw'];
$ip = $_GET['ipw'];
$pc = $_GET['laptopw'];
$keuze = $_GET['keuzew'];

echo "$user <br> $ip <br> $pc <br> $keuze <br>";

//Serverside info
$servername = "172.17.80.153";
$username = "connect";
$password = "123456";
$dbname =  "vbtest";

// Connectie maken
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// connectie testen
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully <br>";

//regels voor de lengte van variabelen
if (strlen($user) <> 4) { echo "geen veranderingen toegestaan";
 die ;}
  if (strlen($ip) > 14) { echo "geen veranderingen toegestaan";
 die ;}
  if (strlen($keuze) > 3) { echo "geen veranderingen toegestaan";
 die ;}
  if (strlen($keuze) < 2) { echo "geen veranderingen toegestaan";
 die ;}

 //Entry toevoegen aan de MySQL
if ($keuze == 'ja') {
$sql = ("INSERT INTO testtbl(Gebruikersnaam, Computernaam, Ipaddress, Keuze) VALUES('".$user."', '".$pc."', '".$ip."', '".$keuze."' )");
}
else
{
$sql = ("INSERT INTO testntbl(Gebruikersnaam, Computernaam, Ipaddress, Keuze) VALUES('".$user."', '".$pc."', '".$ip."', '".$keuze."' )");
$sql2 = ("INSERT INTO testtbl(Gebruikersnaam, Computernaam, Ipaddress, Keuze) VALUES('".$user."', '".$pc."', '".$ip."', '".$keuze."' )");

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
    echo "<br>New second record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('javascript:window.open("", "_self", "");window.close();', '_self');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You have both SQL injection and XSS vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: You'd have to send something back to the client once the PHP is complete.

Comment: The JavaScript already "waits for" the PHP, because PHP won't echo the JavaScript until it's done with the code above, so that can't be the reason the database insertion isn't working.

Comment: @boann this is just the first part of the code (we will make it more secure later) and the further code works without the browser closing

Comment: @deboer: bad attitude. Write secure code to begin with. Going back later just makes your job that much harder. And everyone knows that in programming projects, "later" never comes.

Comment: well you may be right on the harder part but i want this to work first (this will not be the version inplemented but a version to learn to me how it is done) and someone else will look over the code again. please note I'm not a good coder and most of this is found on google hits. but for now i just want it to work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP runs the same way as we read a text document, from left to right, top to bottom. That means that your PHP script gets executed before the javascript redirects. You probably have an error in your PHP code and wont be able to see it because of the javascript redirect. Put die(); before the php closing tag, fix the php code and remove the die();

Example:

```
//this is a piece of your code
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
die(); //This is added to your code
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('javascript:window.open("", "_self", "");window.close();', '_self');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and this works with the same string of data that in the old situation was put in the url to fill in the variables?

Comment: Using AJAX and jQuery for this makes it more complicated, not better. It doesn't solve the problem of the script "being killed" too quickly, because there was never any such problem in the first place.

Comment: Already possible with a trivial echo+die combo. As already used in several places in the question. All you did was add complexity.

Comment: And you made it worse again. Once again, it's easy to see errors in the simple case by `die()`ing, which prevents echoing of the JavaScript. It's not possible to see the errors once you've munged it up with AJAX in that way.